# PHP ignore one SQL SERVER statament

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have simple SQL query inside PHP PDO:

```
IF 
BOOLEAN_EXPRESION
BEGIN
UPDATE QUERY;
SELECT '1' inform;
END;
ELSE
SELECT '0' inform;
```

And it works on MS SQL management studio if true then updating and return 1 as column inform if false then return 0 as column inform but in PHP if true then updating else nothing (1 missing) if false then shows 0. Where is 1?

Comment: I think you need to remove ";" after END

Comment: the `;` tells the server to start a new query

Comment: @Takarii you saying remove ; after update and after select 1?

Comment: Yes. as it stands, you are trying to tell the sql server to do multiple queries, not run through a single one.

Comment: @Takarii nothing still same.

Comment: I swap select 1 with update (select 1 stay as first statement) and it works! Thank You

Comment: I would actually move `BOOLEAN_EXPRESION` into `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause and use [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to confirm the outcome.